# LiferayDispatcherPortlet - what is name of class?

Tags: java, liferay

I have in portlet.xml:

```
<portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
```

And now I want use LiferayDispatcherPortlet, but

```
<portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.LiferayDispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
```

Is wrong, how is correct?

Comment: I haven't heard/seen LiferayDispatcherPortlet.java class anywhere? can you give more information about it

Answer (score 2):

There is no dispatcher class in the liferay. 
You need to pass
 com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet
As the class in the portlet. Or you can create a controller which will extend the above class, and pass the qualified name of that class in portlet tag.
Hope this helps you